# How to access Request from factory in Nestjs?

Tags: nestjs

I'm setting up a custom provider that dependes on some `request` properties. And I wonder if it's possible to achieve this without changing **scope** to `Scope.REQUEST` given that the **request** is undefined inside the factory if the scope is not **REQUEST**.

What is the best approach to access `request` from a factory under `Scope.DEFAULT`?

**app.module.ts**

```
...
@Module({
   ...
   providers: [
      ...
      {
         provide: 'MY_TOKEN',
         useFactory: (req: Request) => {
            ...
            const myFunc = (arg1, arg1) => {
               ...
               return result;
            }
            return myFunc;
         }
      }
   ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This is not possible without making the factory (and therefore  the provider) REQUEST scoped. You basically want to make a new configuration per request, and to do that it **must** be `REQUEST` scoped

---

Add `inject: [REQUEST]`, just like you would `@Inject(REQUEST)` for a constructor. The `inject` is essentially the tokens to be injected into the factory function, just like the constructor is what normally would define what is injected in a regular provider

```js
...
@Module({
   ...
   providers: [
      ...
      {
         provide: 'MY_TOKEN',
         inject: [REQUEST],
         useFactory: (req: Request) => {
            ...
            const myFunc = (arg1, arg1) => {
               ...
               return result;
            }
            return myFunc;
         }
      }
   ]
})
```

This will make whatever injects `MY_TOKEN` `REQUEST` scoped as well, so make sure you are aware of that

Comment: But if I inject `REQUEST` I'll need to do this to the other dependencies too, right?
Otherwise, the other dependencies (providers) will not be injected, given that they are, by default, injected in `DEFAULT` scope. Does it make sense?
At least, it was what happened when I did that. The dependencies weren't injected.

Comment: What other dependencies are you talking about?

Comment: When I inject REQUEST, all the injected dependencies get undefined in my service class. Thanks for the answer @Jay McDoniel.

Comment: Then it's probably in a context t hat doesn't support request scoped providers (like a CRON job or a subscriber or similar

Comment: @JayMcDoniel What is REQUEST? I got  >> cannot find name REQUEST. Did you mean 'Request'? error <<

Comment: `REQUEST` comes from `@nestjs/core`. It's the injection token that Nest correlates to the request object for REQUEST scoped injections